# Python 3 - Multiprocessing same function with different args

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In python 3, I am trying to run the same function with multiple arguments at the same time. I am using multiprocessing in Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit), in Windows 7. I am getting the following error regarding spawn.py:

> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
>   current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
> This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
>   child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
>   in the main module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    ...
```

> The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
>   is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

My code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

#Function to be run
def savedatetime(password,rangestart,rangeend):
    print((password,rangestart,rangeend))

# Inputs to the function
passwords=['p0','p1','p2']
ranges=[(1,10),(10,20),(20,30)]

# Creating the list of processes to append
fileind=0
proc=[]
for rangeind in range(0,len(passwords)):    
    password=passwords[fileind]
    rangestart=ranges[fileind][0]
    rangeend=ranges[fileind][1]
    p = Process(target=savedatetime,args=(password,rangestart,rangeend))            
    proc.append(p)
    fileind=fileind+1
    # running sequentially to check that the function works
    savedatetime(password,rangestart,rangeend)

print(proc)

# Attempting to run simultaneously. This is where the error occurs:
for p in proc:
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Could you please help me to fix my code so the multiple instances of the same function run simultaneously? Thanks!

Comment: In the code: `for p in proc:
    p.start()
    p.join()` you start a process, but you will be blocked to wait the process to finish, since you `p.join()` immdiately.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of your error is, but if you are trying to run processes in parallel you are doing it wrong. `p.join()` will block until `p` is complete. You need to refrain from `join`ing until you have started all of your processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a gatekeeper test to prevent your code from executing again when Windows simulates forking by reimporting your main module. It's why *all* main modules should control their "main-like" behavior with the `if __name__ == '__main__':` gatekeeper check.

The simplest solution is to take all the "main" code, indent it one level, and define a function named `main` that contains it.

The `main` function would be:

```
def main():

    # Inputs to the function
    passwords=['p0','p1','p2']
    ranges=[(1,10),(10,20),(20,30)]

    # Creating the list of processes to append
    ... omitted for brevity ...

    # Attempting to run simultaneously. This is where the error occurs:
    for p in proc:
        p.start()

    # Join after all processes started, so you actually get parallelism
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
```

Then just add the following to the end of your file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `__name__` check prevents your main function from being re-executed when you spawn the worker processes.

Comment: Side-note: Putting all your code in a `main` function usually makes it a little faster too; local variable access in `main` is a simple array lookup on the call stack in the byte code, while accessing globals, in or out of a function, requires a dict lookup, which is more expensive.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Also, I had always wondered why people used the gatekeeper check. Now I know. Thank you!

Comment: @CarlosH: The main reason for doing it is if you have utility functions in the module that you might want to use in other code. The gatekeeper check means that some other piece of code can import you without doing all the things that assume it's the main module for a run. Thus, you could do `from yourmodule import savedatetime` to gain access to `savedatetime` without running all the stuff in `main`. Putting everything in a `main` function is good practice (but not necessary; it could all just be in the `if` block); it ensures your utility functions don't _rely_ on stuff defined in `main`...

Comment: ...which would cause the utility functions to fail when used in normal import mode (rather than main module mode).